# How to use 'Go with'

Tags: sentence-construction

> I think getting up early is kind of difficult to do. And I'm pretty sure that **it is difficult for many people too.**

And I've heard some people saying something like followings, including 'go with'. But, I'm not sure which one is right. Could you help me with this?

> 1. Many people go with me.
> 2. Many people are the same as me.
> 3. Same thing goes with many people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Go with*, or any of the variations you've suggested, is not correct.

The expression you want is [*goes for*.](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/the-same-that-goes-for-sb-sth)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few superfluous words. *And*, there are more than one ways to write it.

My version-

> I think getting up is difficult. And, I'm pretty sure that this goes *the same* with many people as well.

Answer (score 0):

Without rewording the part you're not asking about, I'd recommend this:

> *I think getting up early is kind of difficult to do. And I'm pretty sure that **it's the same for** many people too.*

As for your other alternatives:

> 1. *Many people **go with me**.*
>      This is not what you want. They don't go anywhere with you! Better not use it!
> 2. *Many people **are the same as me**.*
>      This sentence is okay, but it could be improved.
>      Alternatives: *Many people **are [in the same boat](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+same+boat)**.* *Many people **have the same problem**.*
> 3. ***Same thing goes with*** many people.
>      Correction: ***The same [goes for](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/go-for)*** many people. (as user8399's mentioned, don't use *goes with*)
>      (*go for*: sense 7: "to be true or relevant for someone or something")